ERROR: non-conforming drawing primitive definition 6
I am creating a QR code image using ImageMagick and call the following function:
public function done() : string
 {
     if (null === $this->draw) {
         throw new RuntimeException('No image has been started');
     }
     $this->image->drawImage($this->draw);
     $blob = $this->image->getImageBlob();
     $this->draw->clear();
     $this->image->clear();
     $this->draw = null;
     $this->image = null;
     $this->gradientCount = null;

     return $blob;
 }

I sometimes get the following error:
ERROR: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `6' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4459
The stack trace points to the line:
$this->image->drawImage($this->draw);

Has anyone come across this error and how did you fix it?
ImageMagick version:
6.9.10-68
Operating system:
CentOS Linux 7.9
I confirmed that $this->draw is not empty :
$this->draw has the value: ImagickDraw Object
I have searched for:
ERROR: non-conforming drawing primitive definition 6
... I found errors for primitive definition 'text', but found nothing for the primitive definition: 6
